# Want to read data one by one?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am beginner to Android. I want to read all orders one by one and show them in table form. With this code it shows only data of last order.

[image]

```
public class plctovst extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclermanu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;
    TableLayout tableLayout;


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<orders, orderViewHolder> adapter;
    FirebaseDatabase db;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    String cnic;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_plctovst);

        recyclermanu=findViewById(R.id.CartView);
        recyclermanu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        manager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclermanu.setLayoutManager(manager);
        recyclermanu.setAdapter(adapter);

        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("cnic", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        cnic = sharedpreferences.getString("cnic",null);

        db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        ref=db.getReference("AssignedOrdersDetails").child(cnic);
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.e("ASAD",postSnapshot.getKey());
                    FirebaseDatabase db1=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

                    DatabaseReference ref1=db1.getReference("AssignedOrdersDetails").child(cnic).child(postSnapshot.getKey());

                    adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<orders, orderViewHolder>(orders.class,R.layout.order_item_list,orderViewHolder.class,ref1) {


                        @Override
                        protected void populateViewHolder(final orderViewHolder orderViewHolder, final orders order, int i) {

                            // orderViewHolder.order_number.setText(order.ge);


                            //      Toast.makeText(Order.this, "In populate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("ASAD",order.getPrice());

                            orderViewHolder.order_date.setText("Date = "+order.getDate().toString());
                            orderViewHolder.order_time.setText("Time = "+order.getTime().toString());
                            orderViewHolder.order_price.setText("Price = "+order.getPrice().toString());
                            orderViewHolder.order_status.setText("Order Status = "+order.getStatus().toString());




                        }

                    };
                    recyclermanu.setAdapter(adapter);


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });}

//        tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.medicine_list_view);
//        tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);


   //     loadCart();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If so, please show the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If not, I'd recommend getting started with the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start) and [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. What's the problem with this code? When you run this code in a debugger and place breakpoitns, which line doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why need a custom here `ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {`. Why don't you create the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` directly on `db.getReference("AssignedOrdersDetails").child(cnic)`.